# flutter_stripe Build failed with an exception on android

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-stripe

I am using the flutter_stripe plugin for stripe payment. It is working on IOS but on android, I am getting this error . As per flutter_stripe documentation all settings done for android and ios..

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.stripe:stripe-android:20.1.+.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :stripe_android
> > Failed to list versions for com.stripe:stripe-android.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/stripe/stripe-android/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/stripe/stripe-android/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/stripe/stripe-android/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6m 3s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
repositories {

    google()
   // mavenCentral()
    jcenter()


}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3' //4.1.3
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

}
```

}

```
allprojects {
repositories {

    google()
    jcenter()
    //mavenCentral()
}
```

}

```
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}

subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
```

Tried jcenter() and mavenCentral().but getting same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forked and fixed it.

1. Fork [flutter_stripe](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe)
2. Replace `com.stripe:stripe-android`** (`flutter_stripe/packages/stripe_android/android/build.gradle`)

   Add stripe-android to your build.gradle dependencies.

   ```
   dependencies {
       implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:20.4.0'
   }
   ```

   [reference](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android#configuration)
3. Replace flutter_android with the repository you forked
   `flutter_stripe/packages/stripe/pubspec.yaml`

   Like this

   ```yaml
    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      stripe_android:
        git:
          url: https://github.com/<YourName>/flutter_stripe.git
          ref: <Branch Name>
          path: packages/stripe_android
   ```

   [My Repository](https://github.com/makumaaku/flutter_stripe/blob/v3_0_0/packages/stripe/pubspec.yaml#L24-L28)

Comment: Thank you so much. I fixed by changing to implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:20.2.2'